# Navigate from react-dom doesn't re-render the entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, i am trying to display certain items on my navbar when a user is logged in and show something else when a user is logged out. I am using a ternary condition to do this with fragments because i want to display multiple items. When i login, the url and the login form changes but the navbar still remains the same way it was before i logged in. I have to refresh the page to see the new navbar items, what am i doing wrong?

This is my Navbar

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { authenticationService } from "../services/authenticatiion";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "Space-around",
      }}
    >
      <NavLink to="/">
        {" "}
        <h3>Posts</h3>
      </NavLink>

      {authenticationService.isAuthenticated ? (
        <>
          <div
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
              textDecoration: "underline",
            }}
            onClick={() => authenticationService.logout()}
          >
            <h3>Logout</h3>
          </div>
          <NavLink to="/create">
            <h3>Create a Post</h3>
          </NavLink>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <NavLink to="/login">
            {" "}
            <h3>Login</h3>
          </NavLink>{" "}
        </>
      )}

      <NavLink to="/contact">
        {" "}
        <h3>Contact</h3>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

This is my Login form

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from "../helpers";
import { authenticationService } from "../services/authenticatiion";

const Login = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const history = useNavigate();
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    authenticationService
      .login(username, email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        history("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message || error);
      });
  }
  console.log(authenticationService.isAuthenticated);
  if (authenticationService.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate replace to="/" />;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <header>Login</header>

      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          className="text-input"
          type="text"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Password</label>
        <input
          className="text-input"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Email</label>
        <input
          className="text-input"
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit" loading={loading.toString()} disabled={loading}>
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

My app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes,useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import PostList from "./components/PostList";
import PostCreate from "./components/PostCreate";
import PostDetail from "./components/PostDetail";
import PostUpdate from "./components/PostUpdate";
import DeletePost from "./components/DeletePost";
import Layout from "./containers/Layout";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./obs.css";
import "./obs2.css";


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<PostList />} />
          <Route path="/create" element={<PostCreate />} />
          <Route path="/post/:postSlug" element={<PostDetail />} />
          <Route path="/post/:postSlug/update" element={<PostUpdate />} />
          <Route path="/post/:postSlug/delete" element={<DeletePost />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
      <ToastContainer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

authentucation sercice

```
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "../api";
const authAxios = axios.create();

authAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const newConfig = config;
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log(token);
  newConfig.headers = {
    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
  };
  return newConfig;
});

function isAuthenticated() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return token !== null && token !== undefined;
}

function login(username, email, password) {
  return axios
    .post(api.auth.login, {
      username,
      email,
      password,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.key);
      return res;
     
    });

}
function signup(username, email, password1,password2) {
    return axios
      .post(api.auth.register, {
        username,
        email,
        password1,
        password2
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.key);
        return res;
       
      });
    }
    
function logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  window.location.href = '/';
}

const authenticationService = {
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated(),
  logout,
  login,
  signup
};
export { authAxios, authenticationService };
```

I tried to use window.replace but i kept getting some errors, so i just removed it.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for the above example?

Comment: I am using an actual api that hasn't been deployed so the code won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a useEffect hook in your component(Navbar)

```
useEffect(()=>{},[authenticationService.isAuthenticated])
```

Or try passing the isAuthenticated variable as a prop to navbar. React components rerenders everytime the props change

Comment: I get this error "React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'authenticationService.isAuthenticated'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'authenticationService.isAuthenticated' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.",

Comment: Can you share the code for authenticationService ?

Comment: Passing Value as props will rerender the component or you can use a state management tool such as redux to access that variable and pass it as a dependency to useEffect

Comment: I've added the authentication service to my post, i haven't used redux before, can you modify your code to show it passed as props? what i tried gave me errors.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using Context API.